# Error in using detectMSERFeatures function of Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using `detectMSERFeatures` function of Matlab 2014b version, for getting an image's features but this function is giving an error, please help.

Code:

```
colorImage = imread('handicapSign.jpg');
    I = rgb2gray(colorImage);

    % Detect MSER regions.
    [mserRegions, mserConnComp] = detectMSERFeatures(I, ...
        'RegionAreaRange',[200 8000],'ThresholdDelta',4);

    figure
    imshow(I)
```

Error:

```
Error using detectMSERFeatures
Too many output arguments, please help.
```

Comment: What does `which('detectMSERFeatures')` yield? It is possible that you have a file on your path named `detectMSERFeatures.m` which is overshadowing MATLAB's own function.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? I think the second output argument was introduced in 16a.

Comment: I am using R2014b Matlab version. @Navan

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2016a and it your code works fine for me. I did add the plot regions after your code to see it work (see below). Didn't get any output argument error.  plot(mserRegions,'showPixelList',true,'showEllipses',false);

Answer (score 1):

`detectMSERFeatures` returns the second output MSER regions in a connected component structure starting from 16a. Before that, it returned only one output `regions` which is a MSERRegions object. You need to update your code to get only one output from detectMSERFeatures. Depending on what you need to do after `detectMSERFeatures` you can use `extractFeatures` function to extract feature vectors with the output from `detectMSERFeatures`. Checkout the documentation for R2014b, for examples.

Comment: This is actually my question that how can I get these both outputs `mserRegions & mserConnComp` in 2014b version. please answer this.

Comment: @RaeesKhan, use `conComp = bwconncomp(I)`